# Problems when instantiating and initializing objects

Tags: java, objectinstantiation

I've been coding one of my final school projects related to a text file based on weddings. 
I am trying to code a method that will return a wedding object,

(NOTE: weeding object consists of a brideName, groomName, weddingDate, Venue, number of Guests).

In a normal method using Strings. For example, I would merely type

```
String temp = "";
```

run a loop to loop through my array. if statement

```
temp = temp + arr[loop].toString();

return temp;
```

But now dealing with a wedding object when I declare it:

```
Wedding temp; - (As i cant initialize it as there is no brideName etc.)
run loop
if statement
temp = temp + array[loop];

return temp;
```

Here is where i get the error of temp may not have been initialized.

Could anyone help with a suggestion of how to fix this? Thank you so much
Here is what the actual method looks like

```
 public Wedding getWeddingsOnDay(String date, String venue)
{
    Wedding temp;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < counter; loop++)
    {
        if (wedArr[loop].getWeddingDate().equals(date) && wedArr[loop].getVenue().equals(venue))
            temp = wedArr[loop];
        else
            temp = null;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Assign your reference `temp` to an object before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the method this way.

```
public Wedding getWeddingAt(String date, String venue) {
    for (Wedding w : wedArr)
    {
        if (w.getWeddingDate().equals(date) &&
                w.getVenue().equals(venue)) {
            return w;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will say this obviously beacise it is possible that you code will not go into the if block and temp varialble remain unintilized . So , anyone using it need to check null value before using this temp variable .

There are several ways you can remove this error :

1. Ignore this error. As this error will not stop running your code .
2. you can use optional intead of returing null , after this your method will lokks like below method :

   ```
   public Optional<Wedding> getWeddingsOnDay(String date, String venue){

     Optional<Wedding> temp;
     for (int loop = 0; loop < counter; loop++) {
         if (wedArr[loop].getWeddingDate().equals(date) && wedArr[loop].getVenue().equals(venue)) { 
             temp = Optional.of(wedArr[loop]);}
    else{
             temp = Optional.empty(); 
     }
   }
     return temp;    
   }
   ```
3. You need not to use temp at all just return **wedArr[loop] or null**